# Updating properties file from Batch file by skipping and printing comments and blank lines

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am updating a property file using batch file. I would like to know if I can update property file with skipping and printing commented lines and blank lines.
I have some keys in property file which are not having any value by default. 
If I am keeping `=` as delimiter then while doing echo `%%A=%%B`, for the commented lines I am getting an extra `=` at the end of line.

Below is my batch file:

```
echo off
 Set "Parametervalue=dev"
 Set "baseURLvalue=https://prodweb-dev.net/start"
 Set "urlvalue=/client/versions-6.0.1.xml"
 (for /f "usebackq tokens=1* delims==" %%A IN (
 myfile.properties
 ) do if "%%A" equ "Parameter" ( 
 echo Parameter=%Parametervalue%
 ) else if "%%A" equ "baseURL" (
 echo baseURL=%baseURLvalue%
 ) else if "%%A" equ "url" (
 echo url=%urlvalue%
 ) else (echo %%A=%%B)
 )>temp.properties
```

expected updated properties with commented lines and blank lines as original file below:

```
#configuration

#baseURL(mandatory)
baseURL=https://prodweb-dev.net/start

#descriptorurl(mandatory) 
#url=/client/versions-6.0.1.xml
url=/client/versions-6.0.1.xml

#Title (optional, new property, default value is "??") 
Title=

#ClientParameter  (optional, no default value) - parameters which will  be     passed to startup file and are accessible by the client application as     environment variable
Parameter=dev

#BackgroundImage (optional, default Image with Daimler logo) 
BackgroundImage=
```

Below is the output obtained:

```
#configuration=
#baseURL(mandatory)=
baseURL=https://prodweb-dev.net/start
#descriptorurl(mandatory) =
#url=/client/versions-6.0.1.xml
url=/client/versions-6.0.1.xml
#Title (optional, new property, default value is "??") =
Title=
#ClientParameter  (optional, no default value) - parameters which will be     passed to startup file and are accessible by the client application as     environment variable=
Parameter=dev
#BackgroundImage (optional, default Image with Daimler logo) =
BackgroundImage=
```

Comment: So what is the question? Do you want to get rid of the extra `=` ?

Comment: yes. It will be good if I am able to differentiate lines which starts with #.

Comment: ok, but still, do you want to not print them to the new file, or must they be copied over as well? The lines starting with # that is. Or do you just want to have the file exactly as it was, but without changing the strings you do not want to touch?

Comment: So it must be the same, simply changing certain values after you're complete?

Comment: I think that the question may attract more interest if you properly format your batch file code. Can you please do it?

Comment: yes. I need the commented lines to be printed as it is in the original property file. I do not want too touch the lines which stats with # but needs to be printed.

Comment: You are getting this output with an equal sign at the end because you are using `delims==` option. So, if there is no `=` in the line, it will be actually `delims=`. And you are `echo`ing `%%A` which will always have a value, an equal sign and if there is `%%B` print text, else print nothing. So, lines which don't have the equal sign will always be like `text=`.

Comment: Do you want to update the property file or just to create a new one?

Comment: need to update property file. but currently I am doing that by 
(type "C:\Users\USERID\Desktop\New folder\temp.properties")>"C:\Users\USERID\Desktop\New folder\myfile.properties"
del "C:\Users\USERID\Desktop\New folder\temp.properties"

Comment: @double-beep  
There are some properties without default value, If I am not using %%A and equal sign %%B then that properties will not be having equal sign.

Comment: First, you can just replace your file, not create a new one, then deleted and move the new one. As about the second, there is a better way to do that!

Answer (score 1):

This will replace all the text as required leaving the other lines unchanged. I will make a change once at my pc because the positional searches are a temporary measure as I am not able to test from my phone.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "iofile=myfile.properties"
set "_param=Parameter=dev"
set "_base=baseURLvalue=https://prodweb-dev.net/start"
set "_url=url=/client/versions-6.0.1.xml"

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('type "%iofile%" ^| find /v /n "" ^& break ^> "%iofile%"') do (
     set "str=%%a
     set "str=!str:*]=!"
     if "!str:~0,9!"=="Parameter" set "str=%_param%"
     if "!str:~0,7!"=="baseURL" set "str=%_base%"
     if "!str:~0,3!"=="url" set "str=%_url%"
     >>%iofile% echo(!str!
  )
```